# How to find the length of one of the sides of a triangle given the area

Tags: triangles, area

[image]

The triangles are drawn to scale. The first triangle has side lengths of 17, 17, 16 while the second triangle has side lengths of 17,17,$k$. The triangles have the same area.

Find the value of $k$ algebraically.

So for the first triangle, I know that the height of the triangle splits the base into two parts of 8 each. sO then using pythagorean theorem, I get the height to be 15 and then the area is $\frac{1}{2} 16 *15 = 120$

For the second triangle, I'm not sure what to do and I don't know what solving for $k$ algebraically means.

Comment: If we assume the "half" triangles are identical in both cases, only arranged differently, then it's obvious that $k/2=15$ leads to some solution. It's not obvious there are no other solutions though (where our assumption doesn't hold). And this is not "algebraically". Still the simplicity of finding this particular solution deserves a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Exactly the same idea. Split in two parts using the height, and in the half-triangle you have the hypotenuse of $17$ and one of the legs is $k/2$.

1. By the Pythagorean theorem, height $h$ satisfies $h^2 + (k/2)^2 = 17^2$, can you find $h(k)$?
2. Now the area of the big triangle is $k \cdot h(k) /2$, but you already know this is $120$, can you solve for $k$?

**Remark** It's obvious one of the answers will be $k=16$ because then the triangles are identical. Are there other values?

**Update**

You have $$k = \sqrt{4\left(17^2 - h^2\right)} = 2\sqrt{17^2 - h^2},$$ hence the final equation is 
$$
120 = k(h) \cdot h /2
    = \frac{h}{2} \cdot 2\sqrt{17^2 - h^2}
    =  h \sqrt{17^2 - h^2}
$$

To solve this, square both sides to get
$$
120^2 = h^2 \left(17^2 - h^2\right)
$$
and let $z = h^2$ to get a quadratic in $z$.

Comment: well I have that $\frac{k^{2}h}{2} = 120$ so $k^{2}h = 240$ but now I don't know what to do

Comment: I know that $k^{2} = \frac{240}{h}$ and plugged that into the first equation but that doesn't help at all

Comment: i don't know how to find h*k

Comment: @user8290579 see update

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm just not understanding but with your update I get that $k^{2} = 1156-4h^{2}$ I can't take the square root of both sides and get a simple answer because square root doesn't distribute over addition or subtraction right?

Comment: how can I solve for k when there are two unknowns in the equation

Comment: @user130306 you solve for $k$ as a function of $h$. Then the final equation will depend on $h$ and $k$, but you can substitute the expression in $h$ for $k$ and get one equation in $h$. Does this make sense?

Comment: so basically when I look at the second equation, I know that $k = 240/h$, and when I plug that back into the first equation i get $5700 = 1156 h^{2}- 4h^{4}$ is this what you were saying?

Comment: I don't understand how to solve for k as a function of h in the first equation because of the subtraction. I understand how to do it in the second one but the first equation has subtraction. could you show me what you mean please?

Comment: @user130306 see the revamped update

Comment: isn't the area of the big triangle $1/2 k *h$? why do you have $1/2 k(h)*k$ as the area of the big triangle

Comment: and also I think you missed a second h in the equation you wrote under 'hence the final equation is'

Comment: @user130306 $k(h)$ is not $k \times h$, but rather indicates that $k$ is an expression in terms of $h$.

Comment: oh! ok I understand now. so after your final step when I solved it, I get that h = 15, so then that's exactly what I had in my first triangle

Comment: oh and I also get that h = 8, so then if h = 8, then I have $1/2(8)k = 120$ so k = 30 is that correct?

Comment: @user130306 yes, you got it, $h = 8$ or $h=15$

Answer (score 0):

Don’t calculate, cut the triangle along the height instead to get two triangles with sides $8-17-15$. Now glue them together at their common sides of length $8$ to get the wanted triangle; its sides are $17-17-30$.

Alternatively call the angle on top $\phi$.  Then the triangle’s area equals $0.5\cdot 17^2\cdot\sin(\phi)$. Firstly, this shows that there’s exactly one other solution, provided that $\phi\neq\pi/2$.  This other solution has an angle of $\pi-\phi$ on top. For this solution holds that 
$0.5k/17=\sin(\pi/2-\phi/2)=\cos(\phi/2)$. As $\sin(\phi/2)=8/17$ we have
$(8/17)^2+(0.5k/17)^2=1$, from which $k=30$ follows immediately.